# How to use {% with %} along with {% include %} -- Django

Tags: django, django-templates

For example, I have a template file called:

filter.html

```
{{ title }}

code...
```

What I'd like to do is, on a separate template:

```
{% with "Filter by Types" as title %}
  {% include "filter.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

Currently it can't be done. Could someone explain why that is and an alternative way to achieve this?

Background context:

The app base is used for multiple sites. The site admin would only be able to edit the template files to give them a degree of customization, but not the views.py or other core files. So the {{ title }} variable can't really be sent by the views.py.

Comment: I had some similiar problems with multiple sites and ended up with adding different context processors to the different sites. E.g. django's generic views enable you to add some extra context to the view, which you could for example specify in your site's urls.py.

Comment: Why do you say this can't be done? I do exactly that all the time. What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: @Daniel: You're right! I just tried it again and it works. I must've done a typo or some other things wrong when I tried this before. Thanks!

Comment: btw, in Django 1.3, you can do {% include 'filter.html' with title="Filter by Types" %}. It's totally rad: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

This feature fills a massively gaping hole, as your question demonstrates.

Answer (score 4):

I might be missing something but why not just use *extends* and *block* tags?

**base.html**

```
{% block title %}Default title{% endblock %}
```

**filter.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Filter by Types{% endblock %}
```

Check out the documentation on [extends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends), [blocks](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block) and [template inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) for more info.